# MoviePy multiple textClips one after another

Tags: python, text, moviepy

I have an audio file and its script file, that looks like this

```
One day I was playing Fortnite
solos until I got a strange fend
invites I never seen before I joned
it an he said time to play
a game I sruged it of like
no big deal I regreted doing that
but he kept saying time to play
over and over and over ugen
```

My goal is to make a video where voice is followed by text appearing on the screen (next line appears, previous disappears). The way I do it is obviously wrong and it just renders all lines at the beginning of the video stacked on each other + I can not know how much lines of script there will be so doing texts[0], texts[1]... is not an option. Please send help!

My code:

```
videoclip = VideoFileClip("Satisfying Minecraft Parkour.mp4")
audioclip = AudioFileClip(f"audio.mp3")
new_audioclip = CompositeAudioClip([audioclip])

videoclip.audio = new_audioclip
texts = []
with open(f'text.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            txt_clip = TextClip(line, fontsize = 55, color = 'white')
            txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos('center') 
            txt_clip = txt_clip.set_duration(audio_in_seconds/len(str(text))*len(line))
            texts.append(txt_clip)
video = CompositeVideoClip([videoclip, texts[0]])
video = CompositeVideoClip([video, texts[1]])
```